# Python/ Pandas/ DataFrame/ Iteration/ Iterate through rows, find a value, note index, then starting at that index, find another value

Tags: python, pandas, loops

A. I have a dataframe whereby order is important.

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'c1':1,'c2':111123}, {'c1':2, 'c2':1001}, {'c1':3,'c2':11032}, {'c1':4,'c2':11044}, {'c1':5,'c2':11012}, {'c1':6, 'c2':100156}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
print (df)

   c1      c2
0   1  111123
1   2    1001
2   3   11032
3   4   11044
4   5   11012
5   6  100156
```

B. I would like to search for a value in this dataframe return some value from that row and then based on the index of that value I would like to search through the rest of that dataframe starting at that index and find another value and do the same thing while ignoring all values that occurred before this index

Example for the above dataframe:

1. Find value 11032 from column c2, print value at that index for c1
2. Starting at index where 11032 from column c2 was found, search for 11012 from column c2, print value at that index for c1

Thank you.

Comment: What is the expected result for this input?

Comment: And what is the idea behind these searching for these very specific values "11032" and "11012"?

Comment: Is possible some value is not found? If yes, what happened?

Comment: I have modified the example to simply print off the value at c1 as the crux of the question is about finding a value in a dataframe and then using that index to find another value in the same dataframe ignoring everything before that index.

Comment: Q: And what is the idea behind these searching for these very specific values "11032" and "11012"?

A: Take it that it can be any specific values

Comment: Q: Is possible some value is not found? If yes, what happened?

A: Ignore fail state, assume we simply exit the program

Comment: @coldspeed, I am attempting to code a particular behaviour for an analysis I'm doing, but thanks for your thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`) for boolean mask and get first index of first `True` by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

*Notice*:

Solution working if both values are in Series, second one is after first one value in `c2`.

```
a = df['c2'].eq(11032).idxmax()
print (a)
2

b = df.loc[a:, 'c2'].eq(11012).idxmax()
print (b)
4
```

More general solution for return list of tuples by values with theis index and if no first value is match it return empty list. If not matched second, third... value it return only all matched pairs:

```
def get_vals(vals):
    out = []
    idx = 0
    for x in vals:
        m = df.loc[idx:, 'c2'].eq(x)
        if m.any():
            idx = m.idxmax()
            out.append((x, idx))
        else:
            return out
    return out

print (get_vals([11032, 11012]))
[(11032, 2), (11012, 4)]
print (get_vals([10, 11012]))
[]
print (get_vals([11032, 10]))
[(11032, 2)]
print (get_vals([10, 11012, 100156]))
[]
print (get_vals([11032, 11012, 100156]))
[(11032, 2), (11012, 4), (100156, 5)]
print (get_vals([11032, 11012, 10]))
[(11032, 2), (11012, 4)]
print (get_vals([11032, 11012, 111123]))
[(11032, 2), (11012, 4)]
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael this approach solves the issue I was having, thank you.

Comment: @BenjaminPhua - You are welcome! Also added more general solution working with list of values and also works if some value is not match.

Answer (score 1):

Write a generic function called search which uses [df.truncate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html)

```
def search(df,val,prev_index):
    df_tmp = df.truncate(before=prev_index)
    idx = df.index[df['c2'] == val].tolist()[0]
    return df.iloc[idx]['c1'],idx
```

now

```
print(search(df,1001,0))
```

will return

> (2, 1)

```
print(search(df,100156,1)  #you can save idx values i.e. here 1 to a variable and reuse them !
```

will return

> (6 ,5)

Comment: thanks the truncate method is a good idea as well, much appreciated.